# How to display Youtube videos in a jQuery lightbox (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, fancybox

I tried lightbox-plus, fancybox, etc...

But I couldn't figure how to do it.

Those videos are images posts with a link containing a Youtube video:

```
<p><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zUN826BdvV4">
<img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-40" 
title="Screenshot" src="http://localhost/custom-post-type/
wp-content/uploads/2011/01/Screenshot2-150x150.png" 
alt="" width="150" height="150" /></a></p>
```

[Fancybox for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/), for example, let me add a lightbox to images, but if the image links to a Youtube video it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript/JQuery code?  Posting just the HTML is only posting half your problem.

Comment: @jmort253 I'm using the Fancybox for Wordpress plugin. It doesn't require any javascrit, it just works in any link with media attached

Comment: Also, what do you mean it doesn't work?

Comment: There is some kind of JavaScript in play here.  It's not magic.  Is there any JavaScript rendered on your page that could help troubleshoot?  I know you didn't write the JavaScript yourself, but it has to be there, unless Fancybox in Wordpress uses Flash.  I suggest you inspect with Chrome Debugger or Firebug.  I bet it's just something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use PrettyPhoto ([link to site](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/), [link to wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-prettyphoto/)). It is simple to activate:

```
$('a[rel="prettyPhoto"], .myvideolinkclass').prettyPhoto();
```

And the HTML is pretty clean:

```
<a href="http://youtube.com/a-real-youtube-link" rel="prettyPhoto[youtube]">My Awesome Youtube Video</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen the FancyBox Blog?  There is an example there of a YouTube video in a Fancybox:

http://fancybox.net/blog

**Script tag to import FancyBox:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js">
</script>
```

**JavaScript/Jquery to bind click event:**

```
$("#tip4").click(function() {
$.fancybox({
        'padding'       : 0,
        'autoScale'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'title'         : this.title,
        'width'     : 680,
        'height'        : 495,
        'href'          : this.href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/'),
        'type'          : 'swf',
        'swf'           : {
             'wmode'        : 'transparent',
            'allowfullscreen'   : 'true'
        }
    });

return false;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<a id="tip4" title="'Zombieland' Trailer"
    href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=071KqJu7WVo&amp;feature=player_embedded#at=41">
        Try now
</a>
```

Comment: I tried doing that with the Fancybox for Wordpress plugin I think it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe try using the technique on the blog.  Wordpress is pretty good about working with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out [how](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-fancybox-for-wordpress-possible-to-set-width-and-height-of-fancybox):

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><a class="fancybox" href="#welcomevideo"><img src="http://www.howieolson.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/howie-olsen-welcome-video.jpg" width="251px" height="188px" alt="Welcome To High Output"></a></div>

<div style="display:none" id="welcomevideo">
<object width="400" height="300"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=11051269&server=vimeo.com&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&color=00ADEF&fullscreen=1&autoplay=1" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=11051269&server=vimeo.com&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&color=00ADEF&fullscreen=1&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" width="400" height="300"></embed></object>
</div>
```

It seems like it works with links with inline content attached to it.

(Please let me know if there's a better solution to this).

Comment: +1 - That's what I was seeing in the Fancybox Wordpress plug-in forum.  It didn't look right because object is typically used for embedding things like flash, but if it works and is documented as being the working solution, then I say go for it :)